# Exporting orders from Woocommerce to google sheets using webhooks and app script

Tags: wordpress, google-apps-script, google-sheets, webhooks

after deploying the code as webapp
0

I just attach my WooCommerce through webhook in google sheet and get some code from internet for getting orders data on it every things looks fine
[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

There is nothing inserted in my google sheet documents.

```
//this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a POST request
function doPost(e) {
  var myData = JSON.parse([e.postData.contents]);
  var order_created      = myData.date_created;
  var product_name       = myData.line_items[0].name;
  var itemName = myData.line_items[0].name;
  var quantity = myData.line_items[0].quantity;
  var product_items      = quantity + " x " + itemName + "\n"; 
  var product_qty        = myData.line_items[0].quantity;
  var order_total        = myData.total;
  var billing_email      = myData.billing.email;
  var billing_first_name = myData.billing.first_name;
  var billing_phone      = myData.billing.phone;
  var shipping_address   = myData.shipping.address_1;

  var timestamp = new Date();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow([timestamp,order_created,billing_first_name,billing_phone,shipping_address,product_name,product_qty,order_total,billing_email,product_items]);
}
```

I tried to link google sheets with Wordpress via webhook when an order created details of that order will be send to google sheet document,

I expect every time an order created, a row added to my sheet with order details.

Comment: Check executions